# yfinance - SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError) ,PYTHON

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, yfinance, certifi

I have a problem that I have been trying to solve for two weeks without success, I would be happy for the help of the professionals.

I work in an organization with information security, and we need to use the `yfinance` module to download stock prices.
The problem is when Nani tries to download the prices, I get an error message -
`SSLError (SSLCertVerificationError)`

I researched a bit in the code of the `yfinance` module and found that the download is done through the `requests` module, and that within the `requests` module - the approval for the site is taken from the `certifi` module.
It is important to note that the site from which the information is downloaded has an SSL certificate.
(https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/AAPL)
I tried updating the modules but it didn't help either.

I would be happy to help them with this.

The code I'm writing -

```
import yfinance as yf

df = yf.download ('AAPL', period = '5d')
```

The error message I receive -

```
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed

1 Failed download:
- AAPL: No data found for this date range, symbol may be delisted

Process finished with exit code 0
```

When basically what is behind it is a message about SSL (that such a certificate must be found).